# {% requireLogin %} not returning to original page

Tags: login, requirelogin

According to the Craft docs {% requireLogin %} on a page should return the user to the same page after login. This doesn't work for me - the returned page is always the one set in 'postLoginRedirect'.

In the config file, I've got this setup:

```
    'postLogoutRedirect' => 'members/logout',

    'postLoginRedirect' => 'members',

    'loginPath' => 'members/login'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but you probably just want to remove the `postLoginRedirect` setting from the config?

You could also try adding `{{ redirectInput(craft.app.user.returnUrl) }}` to the form.

`craft.app.user.returnUrl` should return the URL that triggered the login.

Comment: I tried that, but if it's removed the user is sent to the default post login URL.

Comment: Hi, have updated my answer with another option. `craft.app.user.returnUrl` should give you the url that you want to redirect to, so setting the ```{{ redirectInput() }}``` value to that should sent the user back to the page that triggered the login.

Comment: Yes that's done it!